# Delete rows of a data frame based on quantity of data in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas data frames `A` and `B`. `B` is a subset of A.

I want to delete all numbers from A if it's in B. **But**, if a number occurs two times in A and 1 time in B then it will only delete 1 occurrence of the number from A.

Here is my sample data sets:

```
df_A                df_B
[Test]              [Test]
1                   1
2                   2         
3                   5 
2                   5 
4
5
5
```

After the operation I want new data frame c as

```
df_C
[Test]
3
2
4
```

Can you please suggest how to do that?

The [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880627/in-pandas-how-to-delete-rows-from-a-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame) removes all occurrences from `A` if present in `B`, not just the first N occurrences.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Pandas, how to delete rows from a Data Frame based on another Data Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880627/in-pandas-how-to-delete-rows-from-a-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame)

Comment: This is not dupe, as question asks to remove only first N occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might do something (stealing SR's setup):

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5]})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1, 2, 5, 5]})

counts = dfA.groupby('A').cumcount()
limits = dfB['B'].value_counts().reindex(dfA.A).fillna(0).values
dfC = dfA.loc[counts >= limits]
```

which gives me

```
In [121]: dfC
Out[121]: 
   A
2  3
3  2
4  4
```

---

This works by using groupby to get the number of times a given value in A has been seen before:

```
In [124]: dfA.groupby('A').cumcount()
Out[124]: 
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    1
dtype: int64
```

and using `value_counts` to get the limits which we then reindex to match the counts:

```
In [139]: dfB['B'].value_counts()
Out[139]: 
5    2
2    1
1    1
Name: B, dtype: int64

In [140]: dfB['B'].value_counts().reindex(dfA.A)
Out[140]: 
A
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    NaN
2    1.0
4    NaN
5    2.0
5    2.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create some intermediate values which contain the occurrence number for each value, then you can use [`pandas.Series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to create a logical index of which rows of the dataframe to exclude like:

#### Code:

```
from collections import Counter

def occurrences_number(column):

    def occurrence_number(value, accumulator):
        """ tuple of value and occurrence number of value """
        accumulator[value] += 1
        return value, accumulator[value]

    occurrences = Counter()
    return column.apply(lambda x: occurrence_number(x, occurrences))

def find_not_in_by_occurrence_number(data, not_in):
    not_in_indices = ~occurrences_number(data).isin(occurrences_number(not_in))
    return data[not_in_indices].reset_index()
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5]})
dfB = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1, 2, 5, 5]})
print(dfA)
print(dfB)

dfC = find_not_in_by_occurrence_number(dfA.A, dfB.B).A

print (dfC)
```

#### Results:

```
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  2
4  4
5  5
6  5

   B
0  1
1  2
2  5
3  5

0    3
1    2
2    4
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

In this problem, you can make use of [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) and [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). For drop, you will need to know the indexes of rows that you want to discard.

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 5}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Test': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 5}})
c_df2 = Counter(df2.Test)

indexes_to_remove_2d = [df.index[df['Test'] == k].tolist()[:v] 
                        for k, v in c_df2.items()]
# [[0], [1], [5, 6]]
merged = list(itertools.chain(*indexes_to_remove_2d))
# [0, 1, 5, 6]
df.drop(merged)

    Test
2   3
3   2
4   4
```

`indexes_2d` generates those indexes that fits the value `k` in the counter with `df.index[df['Test'] == k]` and has a `[:v]` to limit the size of indexes we take from.

Then, we merge these `indexes` with `itertools.chain`. Finally drop rows with these indexes.

Thanks for Stephan Ranch to point out the order problem.

Comment: @StephenRauch That's true! Will emphasize it.