# How to remove rows from Pandas dataframe if the same row exists in another dataframe but end up with all columns from both df

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different Pandas data-frames that have one column in common. I have seen similar questions on Stack overflow but none that seem to end up with the columns from both dataframes so please read below before marking as duplicate.

Example:

dataframe 1

```
ID  col1 col2  ...
1    9    5
2    8    4
3    7    3 
4    6    2
```

dataframe 2

```
ID  col3  col4  ...
3    11     15
4    12     16
7    13     17
```

What I want to achieve is a dataframe with columns from both dataframes but without the ID's found in dataframe2. i.e:

desired result:

```
ID  col1 col2  col3  col4
1    9    5     -     -
2    8    4     -     -
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can yoiu add some numbers instead `-` ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe) help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a left join to get only the `id`'s in the first data frame and not the second data frame while also keeping all the second data frames columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"id": [1, 2, 3, 4], "col1": [9, 8, 7, 6], "col2": [5, 4, 3, 2]},
    columns=["id", "col1", "col2"],
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"id": [3, 4, 7], "col3": [11, 12, 13], "col4": [15, 16, 17]},
    columns=["id", "col3", "col4"],
)

df_1_2 = df1.merge(df2, on="id", how="left", indicator=True)

df_1_not_2 = df_1_2[df_1_2["_merge"] == "left_only"].drop(columns=["_merge"])
```

which returns

```
   id  col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1     9     5   NaN   NaN
1   2     8     4   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 11):

Looks like a simple [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) will work for what you want:

```
df1.drop(df2.index, errors='ignore', axis=0)

     col1  col2
ID            
1      9     5
2      8     4
```

Note that this assumes that `ID` is the index, otherwise use [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df1[~df1.ID.isin(df2.ID)]

    ID  col1  col2
0   1     9     5
1   2     8     4
```