# Python: How to remove rows which are in other dataframe?

Tags: python

I have two dataframes:

First:

```
                         tif_pobrany
0  65926_504019_N-33-127-B-d-3-4.tif
1  65926_504618_N-33-139-D-b-1-3.tif
2  65926_504670_N-33-140-A-a-2-3.tif
3   66533_595038_N-33-79-C-b-3-3.tif
4   66533_595135_N-33-79-D-d-3-4.tif
```

Second:

```
                                                 url            godlo  ... row_num                        nazwa_tifa
0  https://opendata.geoportal.gov.pl/ortofotomapa...  M-34-68-C-a-1-2  ...   48004  73231_904142_M-34-68-C-a-1-2.tif
1  https://opendata.geoportal.gov.pl/ortofotomapa...  M-34-68-C-a-3-1  ...   48011  73231_904127_M-34-68-C-a-3-1.tif
2  https://opendata.geoportal.gov.pl/ortofotomapa...  M-34-68-C-a-3-2  ...   48012  73231_904336_M-34-68-C-a-3-2.tif
3  https://opendata.geoportal.gov.pl/ortofotomapa...  M-34-68-C-a-3-3  ...   48013  73231_904286_M-34-68-C-a-3-3.tif
4  https://opendata.geoportal.gov.pl/ortofotomapa...  M-34-68-C-a-4-2  ...   48016  73231_904263_M-34-68-C-a-4-2.tif
```

How can I delete rows in second dataframe which have the same 'nazwa_tifa' like in the first dataframe 'tif_pobrany'?

Something like this:

```
for index, row in second.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in first.iterrows():
        if row['nazwa_tifa'] == row2['tif_pobrany']:
            del row
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello. please check my answer and let me know if it fixed your issue!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Pandas, how to delete rows from a Data Frame based on another Data Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880627/in-pandas-how-to-delete-rows-from-a-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame)

Answer (score 0):

considering `df1` and `df2` are names of your dataframes respectively:

```py
df2 = df2[df2['nazwa_tifa'].isin(df1['tif_pobrany'])]
```

#### How it works?

- The [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) function is used to check whether values inside a `Pandas` series are present in another `Pandas` series.
- Then, an array of `True/False` values are passed to `df2`, so it selects only rows wherever the condition is `True`.
- Finally, an assignment is used to replace `df2` with the new dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your data:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col2":[1,3,4,9,8]})


df1.drop(df1[df1.col1.isin(df2.col2)].index, inplace = True)
print(df1)
```

output:

```
   col1
1     2
4     5
```