# How to exclude data present on another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to exclude data that is filtered on another data frame using pandas jupyter. An example of the data frame can be seen below.

Data frame 1:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| AB-01 | 2.65 |
| AB-02 | 3.6 |
| AB-03 | 5.6 |
| AB-04 | 7.6 |
| AB-05 | 2 |

Dataframe 2:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| AB-01 | 2.65 |
| AB-02 | 3.6 |

Desired outcome:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| AB-03 | 5.6 |
| AB-04 | 7.6 |
| AB-05 | 2 |

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880627/in-pandas-how-to-delete-rows-from-a-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isin`

```py
out = df1[~df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])]
```

```
print(out)

      ID  Amount
2  AB-03     5.6
3  AB-04     7.6
4  AB-05     2.0
```