# How to drop a single cell in a pandas dataframe that matches a value in a column of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I'm trying to delete the cells contain survey links that has been completed.

Information table is like this:

| Person | ID | webName1 | webURL1 | webName2 | webURL2 | webName3 | webURL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | aa | x | ht\tp://aa-x | o | ht\tp://aa-o | p | ht\tp://aa-p |
| B | bb | n | ht\tp://aa-n | x | ht\tp://aa-x |  |  |

There will be no duplicate web link, different person has different number of links

The result table contains the links:

| answer1 | answer2 | link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| asd | asd | ht\tp://aa-x |
| sdf | sdf | ht\tp://bb-x |

I would like to match the result table to the information table and delete the web name and web url of the information table that is also in the result table, please give me some advice of simple ways to do it, if I iterate all cells in the dataframe, it will be too time-consuming.

I would like the final look to be:

Information table:

| Person | ID | webName1 | webURL1 | webName2 | webURL2 | webName3 | webURL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | aa | o | ht\tp://aa-o | p | ht\tp://aa-p |  |  |
| B | bb | n | ht\tp://aa-n |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Pandas, how to delete rows from a Data Frame based on another Data Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880627/in-pandas-how-to-delete-rows-from-a-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame)

Comment: Please include the error or the issue in your trial method. It would be easy to understand and expect an explanation in the approach you already trying to do, instead of asking a straight forward question.

Comment: @JoyNa Hi Friend, thank you for your help! I actually read almost all the similar posts online, but my case is a bit different. I need to delete two cells as a set if the link matches one record in the result, and I would like to keep the same format after all the deletion is done, so I guess transforming the table will be the best way. I tried to use loop to locate every cell that matches the result table and delete one by one, but it's too complicated, so I came here to ask for a better way to solve it. But thank you for thinking about my question and tried to provide help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

step1. make wide to long & delete row that have df1 content

```
tmp = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['webName', 'webURL'], i=['Person', 'ID'], j='val')\
        .reset_index().drop('val', axis=1)\
        .mask(lambda x: x['webURL'].isin(df1['link'])).dropna()
```

tmp :

```
    Person  ID  webName webURL
1   A       aa  o       ht\tp://aa-o
2   A       aa  p       ht\tp://aa-p
3   B       bb  n       ht\tp://aa-n
```

step2. make long to wide

```
grp = tmp.groupby(['Person', 'ID']).cumcount().add(1).astype('str')
tmp1 = tmp.assign(grp=grp).pivot(index=['Person', 'ID'], columns='grp', values=['webName', 'webURL'])\
          .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
out = tmp1.set_axis(tmp1.columns.map(lambda x: ''.join(x)), axis=1)\
          .reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

`out` :

[image]

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Person': ['A', 'B'], 'ID': ['aa', 'bb'], 'webName1': ['x', 'n'], 'webURL1': ['ht\\tp://aa-x', 'ht\\tp://aa-n'], 
         'webName2': ['o', 'x'], 'webURL2': ['ht\\tp://aa-o', 'ht\\tp://aa-x'], 
         'webName3': ['p', None], 'webURL3': ['ht\\tp://aa-p', None]}
data2 = {'answer1': ['asd', 'sdf'], 'answer2': ['asd', 'sdf'], 
         'link': ['ht\\tp://aa-x', 'ht\\tp://bb-x']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it in my real dataset and it works perfectly! And I learned the idea of transforming the data from wide to long for simpler operation!

Comment: @Awwwwwan Good to hear. If problem is solved, select answer for next people.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option (*without reshaping techniques*) :

```
urls = df1.filter(like="webURL"); names = df1.filter(like="webName")
is_info_recognized = urls.isin(df2["link"].tolist()).to_numpy()

fn = lambda s: ((t:=s.loc[s.first_valid_index():]).set_axis(s.index[:len(t)]))

urls = urls.mask(is_info_recognized).transform(fn, axis=1)
names = names.mask(is_info_recognized).transform(fn, axis=1)

out = pd.concat([df1[["Person", "ID"]], urls, names], axis=1).reindex_like(df1)
```

Output :

|  | Person | ID | webName1 | webURL1 | webName2 | webURL2 | webName3 | webURL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | aa | o | ht\tp://aa-o | p | ht\tp://aa-p |  |  |
| 1 | B | bb | n | ht\tp://aa-n |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's ingenious! I'll definitely try it!